# How to get count (distribution of values) of date difference between 2 columns using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, distribution

Hoping someone might be able to help; I have 2 tables which can be joined with a column `ID`.

In Table 1 there is a column `created_date`, in table 2 the column is `firstorderdate`. I would like to subtract the first order date from created date to get number of days and then get a count for the different values ideally ordered descending. Effectively I am trying to look at distribution of the date differences.

I have created a SQL fiddle to help show what my schema might look like. My date columns can contain null values and I am only interested if they are both not null if that makes sense.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9adbca

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Date functions are quite vendor-specific.

Comment: It would also help if you could show the result that you would expect.

Comment: It's Oracle SQL but that's about as much as I know

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you find with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL from your provided sqlfiddle.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(t2.FirstOrderDate, t1.created_date) as 'DaysBetween'
       , Count(1)
FROM Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.FirstOrderDate is not null
and t1.created_date is not null
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(t2.FirstOrderDate, t1.created_date)
```

Comment: I will give this a try, I realised I messed up my SQLfiddle example as It hadn't put the 2nd table in so appreciate your response has the join. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `min()` to find the difference between the first order date and the created date. Then count over the result of that query.

You don’t even need the denormalised firstOrderDate column; just join to orders.

Something like:

```
select
    days,
    count(*)
from (
    select min(datediff(createdDate, orderDate)) as days
    from users
    join orders on orders.userId = users.id
    group by users.id) x
order by days
```